# OpenMP/C++: Parallel for loop with reduction afterwards - best practice?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Given the following code...

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < clusters.size(); ++i)
{
    const std::set<int>& cluster = clusters[i];
    // ... expensive calculations ...
    for (int j : cluster)
        velocity[j] += f(j); 
}
```

...which I would like to run on multiple CPUs/cores. The function `f` does not use `velocity`.

A simple `#pragma omp parallel for` before the first for loop will produce unpredictable/wrong results, because the `std::vector<T> velocity` is modified in the inner loop. Multiple threads may access and (try to) modify the same element of `velocity` at the same time.

I think the first solution would be to write `#pragma omp atomic` before the `velocity[j] += f(j);`operation. This gives me a compile error (might have something to do with the elements being of type `Eigen::Vector3d` or `velocity` being a class member). Also, I read atomic operations are very **slow** compared to having a private variable for each thread and doing a reduction in the end. So that's what I would like to do, I think.

I have come up with this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    // these variables are local to each thread
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> velocity_local(velocity.size());
    std::fill(velocity_local.begin(), velocity_local.end(), Eigen::Vector3d(0,0,0));

    #pragma omp for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < clusters.size(); ++i)
    {
        const std::set<int>& cluster = clusters[i];
        // ... expensive calculations ...
        for (int j : cluster)
            velocity_local[j] += f(j); // save results from the previous calculations
    } 

    // now each thread can save its results to the global variable
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < velocity_local.size(); ++i)
            velocity[i] += velocity_local[i];
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution? Is it the *best* solution? (Is it even *correct*?)

Further thoughts: Using the `reduce` clause (instead of the `critical` section) throws a compiler error. I think this is because `velocity` is a class member.

I have tried to find a question with a similar problem, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073639/openmp-with-parallel-reduction-in-for-loop) question looks like it's almost the same. But I think my case *might* differ because the last step includes a `for` loop. Also the question whether this is the best approach still holds.

**Edit:** As request per comment: The `reduction` clause...

```
    #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:velocity)
    for (omp_int i = 0; i < velocity_local.size(); ++i)
        velocity[i] += velocity_local[i];
```

...throws the following error:

*error C3028: 'ShapeMatching::velocity' : only a variable or static data member can be used in a data-sharing clause*

(similar error with `g++`)

Comment: Share the code using reduce that errors so fixes can be suggested.

Comment: @Jeff done. [enough characters]

Comment: Have you considered ppl?  The code to write "self reducing data" is slick there, and doesn't have to be primitives.  Basically you describe what the thread-load data is, and how to combine two thread-local datas, and it does the rest.

Comment: OpenMP doesn't know how to reduce over an STL container. I can't remember if simple arrays are supported.

Comment: @Yakk what is "ppl"?
@Jeff Seems like OMP cannot reduce over class members (only local variables) and OMP also cannot reduce over arrays. Just scalar values (like `int`) are alowed for a reduce.

Comment: parallel patterns library.  Your error indicates you are compiling using MSVC most likely.

Comment: @Yakk It need this project to compile on both Windows (vc++) and Linux (g++)

Comment: Parallelize the inner loop over `cluster`.

Comment: @Zboson How would that help? Please read my question again to see why parallelizing over this loop is not possible (tl;dr: write access to the same variable). Also this loop is not very epensive compared to the outer loop.

Comment: When you do the reduction yourself you need to change `velocity[j] += f(j);` to `velocity_local[j] += f(j);

Comment: The only reason parallelizing the inner loop may not be possible is if the container (`std::set`) does not have random access. You also wrote `// ... expensive calculations ...` I guess you mean these are calculations your removed and you're not referring to the inner loop?

Comment: You an do this with or without a critical section [fill-histograms-array reduction-in-parallel-with-openmp-without-using-a-critic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789242/fill-histograms-array-reduction-in-parallel-with-openmp-without-using-a-critic).

Comment: @Zboson Different threads may try to write so the same `velocity[i]` memory address. How would it be possible to account for this without any `critical`, `single` or `atomic` section? Please elaborate on this, you may also post an answer, which might be more suitable for further discussion.

As for your last question: "expensive calculations" do most of the computational work. They are referred to in the loop over `cluster`s, as the results of the "expensive calculations" are written to the `velocity` variable in this loop.

Comment: You were right about writing `velocity_local[j] += f(j);` in the second block of code. Thanks, I fixed it in the question.

Comment: I forgot to add that you can add `nowait`. I mean you can do `#pragma omp for nowait` in your first loop.

Comment: @Zboson thanks, but that does not seem to affect performance. Isn't there an implicit barrier before the critical section anway?

Comment: @Micha, `nowait` removes the implicit barrier (that's the whole point of `nowait`). The barrier is unnecessary in this case even if it does not effect performance in your case. At the very least it helps you understand what is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing an array reduction. I have described this several times (e.g. [reducing an array in openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413995/reducing-on-array-in-openmp/20421200#20421200) and [fill histograms array reduction in parallel with openmp without using a critical section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789242/fill-histograms-array-reduction-in-parallel-with-openmp-without-using-a-critic)).  You can do this with and without a critical section.

You have already done this correctly with a critical section (in your recent edit) so let me describe how to do this without a critical section.

---

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> velocitya;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    const int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    const int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
    const int vsize = velocity.size();

    #pragma omp single
    velocitya.resize(vsize*nthreads);
    std::fill(velocitya.begin()+vsize*ithread, velocitya.begin()+vsize*(ithread+1), 
              Eigen::Vector3d(0,0,0));

    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < clusters.size(); i++) {
        const std::set<int>& cluster = clusters[i];
        // ... expensive calculations ...
        for (int j : cluster) velocitya[ithread*vsize+j] += f(j);
    } 

    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for(int i=0; i<vsize; i++) {
        for(int t=0; t<nthreads; t++) {
            velocity[i] += velocitya[vsize*t + i];
        }
    }
}
```

This method requires extra care/tuning due to false sharing which I have not done.

As to which method is better you will have to test.